# Troubleshooting: Can't Generate Hive Adapter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Can't generate Hive adapter. After I run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` I get the following output in the terminal:

```
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 327ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 59ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 644ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 12ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 37ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 58ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
```

No file is generated meanwhile...

My code is as follows:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'person.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Person {
  Person({required this.name, required this.age});
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  int age;
}
```

my dependencies are the following:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
  firebase_core: ^2.11.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.5.0
  go_router: ^7.0.0
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  get_it: ^7.6.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.11
  flutter_map: ^4.0.0
  enhanced_enum: ^0.2.4
  twitter_login: ^4.4.0
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  analyzer: ^5.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.5
  hive_generator: ^2.0.0
```

also some aditional info if needed:

- minSdkVersion 21
- flutter.versionName=1.0.0